# Hangman code in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to write a hangman program in C.

Occasionally, some sentences appear twice in the program's output. The program is also intolerant of user inputs other than 1. How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* contant declarations */
#define NUM_TRIES_ALLOWED 10

int main() {

    /* variable declarations */
    int num_letters = 0, /* length of word char array */
    count = 0, /* for word char array       */
    tries = 0, /* total tries user has used */
    num_vis_chars = 0, /* # of visible characters   */
    correct_guesses = 0, /* # of correct guesses      */
    correct_flag = 0, /* was guess correct?        */
    repeat_flag = 0, /* was guess a repeat?       */
    choice;

    char guess, guessword;

    /* array declarations */
    char word[255] = " ";
    char incorrect_letters[255] = " ";
    /* get word */
    puts("Enter a word for player to guess.");
    gets(word);

    ("Ready to start!\n");

    num_letters = strlen(word);

    char visible_word[num_letters]; /* displays correct guesses */
    /* initialize visble_word */
    for (count = 0; count < num_letters; count++)
        visible_word[count] = '*';

    visible_word[num_letters] = '\0';

    if (guess == visible_word[count]) {

        while (tries < NUM_TRIES_ALLOWED) {

            printf("The word is: %s\n\n", visible_word);
            printf("Number of turns remaining: %d", NUM_TRIES_ALLOWED - tries);

            printf(
                    "\nWould you like to guess the word [w] or guess a letter [l]:");
            choice = getchar();

            if (choice == 'l') {

                printf("\nWhat letter have you chosen?:\t ");
                scanf(" %c", &guess);
            }

            /* match guess against previous guesses */
            for (count = 0; count < num_letters; count++)
                if (guess == visible_word[count]
                        || guess == incorrect_letters[count]) {
                    repeat_flag = 1;
                    correct_flag = 1;
                    break;
                }

            if (repeat_flag == 0)
                /* check for matches in string */
                for (count = 0; count < num_letters; count++) {
                    if (guess == word[count]) {
                        visible_word[count] = guess;
                        correct_guesses++;
                        printf(
                                "\n**************************************************************\n\n");
                        printf("Good choice!\n\n");

                        if (correct_guesses == num_letters) {
                            puts("\n\nCONGRATULATIONS! You guessed the word!");
                            printf("WORD: %s\n\n", visible_word);
                            exit(0);
                        }

                        correct_flag = 1;
                    }

                }

            if (correct_flag == 0) {
                incorrect_letters[tries] = guess;
                tries++;
                printf(
                        "\n**************************************************************\n\n");
                printf("Bad choice!\n\n");

            }

            /* reset flags */
            repeat_flag = 0;
            correct_flag = 0;

        }

        puts("You did not guess the word.");
        printf("WORD: %s\n\n", visible_word);

    }
    if (choice = 'w') {

        printf("\nWhat word have you chosen?:\t ");

        scanf("%s", &guessword);

        if (guessword == word) {
            printf("CONGRATULATIONS! You guessed the word!");
        } else {
            printf("nops");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your actual code  (yours is missing some {}), give a short test case which goes wrong, and explain exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: This code as shown won't even compile, so it must not be your actual code.  Too much for SO to debug, you may find the instructions [here](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) useful.

Comment: Chances are good that the problem is due to the use of `scanf()` and its confusing behaviour when reading from the terminal. Suggest not using this, and use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: this looks like C code not C# code also can't stand to look at poorly formatted code especially when the curly braces don't line up in a readable fashion.. ugg

Comment: If you're writing that in C#, and that is really the code you wrote, I think you may have a _little_ problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest providing functions for this code. The code is difficult to read and follow. Start with first creating a menu function, then get user input function; also do checks with-in the function that verify that the input if valid before it sends a character back. Then check to see if the guess is correct and post the response using a function. You will find that if you draw out your code and create the necessary functions it will be much easier to follow and debug.

print_menu() displays the options for the user and an exit choice.

get_user_input()  gets the user input with checking to see that it is valid input

print_remaining()  prints remaining and guessed characters of the word at play

Note if you for instance are getting a char from the user and they enter a letter.

```
 scanf_s("%c", &guess, _countof(guess));
```

Note: _countof(ArrayName) simply just verifies that there is enough space for the placement of the char or string that is going to be assigned. Make sure to #include "stdlib.h" file for this function.

The reason for using scanf_s is that it reads over whitespaces. It dose not read the bad input and if you encounter some from the user, it puts the bad input back into the input buffer where it got if from. The scanf_s() has a return value and its value is going to be how many correct input responses were filled. Meaning this if %c actually read a char then the return value will be 1. if you got a 4 for the entry it will put the four back and return a 0. Good way to read input.  getchar() also works well with this but has some detailed conditions that could cause some grief if not understood. Would be something to consider.

```
while(scanf_s("%c", &guess, _countof(guess)) != 1 )  
 // clear the input buffer and then try again.
```

Then you just clear the input buffer with

```
 while(getchar() != '\n')  
   continue;
```

Above: Clears everything in the input buffer up to and including the newline char. Then, ask the user to enter valid input this time.

If you getting stuff that is printing twice that tells me that the loop is running past its exit condition. If your exit condition has anything to do with reading input. The above loop will take care of any information chillen in the input buffer. Hope this helps. Focus on only calling functions in the actual code. Makes debugging much easier.